# How do I removeAttribute() hidden from p2? doesn't seem to do anything as is

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the attribute of an object with removeAttribute to take away the hidden status of it but so far nothing seems to work.

My code seems to have no effect. Am I doing something wrong?

```
function changePage() {
    document.getElementById.("p2");
    p2.removeAtribute.("hidden") ;
}
```

I've also tried it all on one line as well like so

```
function changePage() {
    document.getElementById.("p2").p2.removeAtribute.("hidden") ;
}
```

Comment: check your console

Comment: `document.getElementById("p2").removeAttribute("hidden") ;` attribute has 2 T's and don't pot dots in every crack and crevice you see there's a pattern if you pay attention

Comment: Thanks I completely missed that typo :) This is my first exposure to these particular commands so the pattern hasn't become apparent to me yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the use of dots before opening parentheses.

E.g.

`document.getElementById.("p2").p2.removeAtribute.("hidden")` should be `document.getElementById("p2").removeAtribute("hidden")`

(You are also referencing the element by id after you just retrieved it, which is unnecessary.)

Your first example didn't work because you retrieved the element and did nothing with it, then tried to access a p2 variable that wasn't declared.  Again, you also have the `.` before parentheses.

Here's the js example:

```js
function changeVisibility()
{
 var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
  
  switch (p2.style.visibility)
  {
   case 'hidden':
     document.getElementById('p2').style.visibility = 'visible';
      break;
    case 'visible':
      document.getElementById('p2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="p2" style="visibility:hidden">
test
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="changeVisibility()">
  change visibility with basic js
</button>
```

And here's the jQuery example:

```js
function changePage()
{
 $('#p2').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p2" style="display:none">
test
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="changePage()">
  change visibility with basic js
</button>
```

The basic JS version uses the `visibility` style, and you can see that it doesn't collapse the element, it only makes it invisible.

jQuery has a nice built-in `.toggle` function that changes the display of the element. If it is hidden, it collapses the element. When the element is displayed, it is re-assigned whatever the `display` style is for that element.  Building that in basic js would take a lot more work, as you are then tracking state (if you want to make the method reusable).  You can make jQuery work similarly to the basic js version if you use the css properties, but `toggle` is quite nice and simple.

Your main issue is that you were mixing the getting of the element with methods that are only available on jQuery objects. I suggest reading the jQuery tutorials for basic accessors, which can get elements by id, class name, etc.

Comment: So this should work?  It doesn't return an error but also doesn't seem to do anything when I run it.                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                              function changePage() {document.getElementById("p2").removeAtribute("hidden");
  
}

Comment: No, sorry, I'll update the code sample. You are actually mixing vanilla js with jQuery syntax. Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's jQuery  here is the latest bit I have function changePage() {document.getElementById("p2").removeAttribute("hidden");
   


}

Comment: I updated the answer with some examples. I highly recommend reading through some of the starting docs for jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, i'll read through them tonight I appreciate the help :)